# ASP Classic - Passing form data to Iframe

Tags: forms, iframe, asp-classic

I'm looking to pass data from a form into an iFrame, but I have a slight problem.

- The form page I can edit with no restrictions
- The page I send the data to **I cannot edit** unless its html or JavaScript
- The data needs to end up in an iframe within this page, which I can edit with no restrictions

I'm incorporating a search function into a CMS system which is why I cannot edit the iframe's parent page, and why I am using iframes at all.

At the moment the data sends to the parent page but is not picked up within the iframe, I am sending via the POST method.

Comment: are the pages on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

I got it..

Added and extra page which converted the post data into session data,

if anyone knows a better way i would like to hear it though.

And they are the same domain, but editing the CMS system would have taken ages to look through as its not mainstream or developed by me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying the problem, but can't you use the "target" attribute of the form tag to post to the Iframe?

Comment: I tried that with the code below, but for some reason it opens in a new window as if I was pointing to "_blank" and still doesn't pass the info through.
<form action="holder.asp" method="post" target="mainframe" class="cmxform " name="form1"> ----> <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="mainframe" id="mainframe" src="searchAction2.asp"></iframe>

Comment: Ah, holder.asp contains the frame "mainframe". In that case this doesn't work, you can submit to an already existing frame, but not to a frame on a page that has yet to be loaded.
You could POST directly to searchAction2.asp, but then you'll miss the holder.asp page around it. You'd be posting directly to the frame page...
What you could do is use XMLserverHTTP to post the data to the correct page (searchAction2.asp), and then redirect to holder.asp.

Comment: would this still allow me to load the searchAction2.asp within an iframe on holder.asp with the correct results?

Comment: hmmm, good one, no. Using xmlserverHttp you'd be posting the data to searchAction2.asp "under water", and _after_ that load holder.asp. The data would be POSTed, but you are right, any results won't show up... Tricky one, this.